# Deleting partially duplicate rows from a table

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

We have a table with the following schema:

```
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field  | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name   | varchar(128)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| label  | varchar(10)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| f1     | varchar(8)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| f2     | varchar(6)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

We would like to consider all rows where the name-label pair is non-distinct to be duplicates (i.e. ignoring f1 and f2).  In such cases we would like to delete the duplicate rows by retaining only the row with the highest id (which incidentally would have been entered in the table at a later time, and therefore assumed to be more current).

What would be the most efficient way to realize it in MySQL 5.6.51?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN itself and delete the row with smaller `id`

```
DELETE a
FROM duplicates a
JOIN duplicates b ON a.label = b.label AND a.name = b.name
WHERE a.id < b.id
```

`name` could be `NULL`, if `NULL` is considered duplicate:

```
DELETE a
FROM duplicates a
JOIN duplicates b ON a.label = b.label AND COALESCE(a.name, '') = COALESCE(b.name, '')
WHERE a.id < b.id
```